# Qt: How to send a SQLTableModel from server to client

Tags: c++, qt, client-server, qbytearray, qsqltablemodel

I am working on a client-server project. On the client side, I have a few GUI windows containing different views (QTableView, QListView). I can send messages to the server just fine using the following method:

```
QByteArray bArray;
QDataStream out(&bArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_7);
//....//
out << quint16(0) << message;
out.device()->seek(0)
out.quint16(bArray.size() - sizeof(quint16));
socket.write(block);
```

My problem however comes on my server side. My server will receive the message, go through a couple of steps reading the message to decide the necessary info to get from the SQL database, run the Query returning a Model(QSqlTableModel, QSqlQueryModel), but should then send the respective model back to the client.

Is there any way for me to send this model back to the server?

Comment: qxt allows for that however I believe the project is no longer maintained. http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtsqlpackagemodel.html

Comment: I still use qxt in my software I develop but use a github fork for Qt5 support. Although I do not use the sql classes from qxt.

Comment: Anybody know of a way to do this without qxt?

Comment: You probably will have to write your own code similar to their implementation.